# integrating Django with a console application

Tags: python, django

I have a query related to Django - to which I am new.

I already have a console application written in Python. It does some heavy processing based on the input and returns a sequence of strings.

What I'd like from Django is to get the input in the form of an HTML form and then pass it on to this console application, then the output from that console application should be displayed on a webpage. I'm not using any models - just `form.py`, `urls.py` and `view.py`.

The problem is I am able to process the HTML form and get its input. I am passing that value to the console application in the `view.py` - but I'm not able to get the results.

Any idea why?? The console applications code is inside the django folder.

Here's my current code:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from app.forms import Search

from lib.console import applicaiton

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): 
            search = form.cleaned_data['search']
            # This is where i pass my console application
            app = application()
            tempString = app.getValue(search)
            # am trying to print. But its empty. 
            # when we print it will print it the webservers console.
            print tempString
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'value' : tempString}
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class Search(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: can you paste related files or functions in here?

Comment: Some help would be much apprciated. even if there is any other web framework which can do the job would be fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Bala you're welcome - is `from lib.console import applicaiton` a typo ?

Comment: It's just example . I am importing the console application

Comment: Please tell me if it's possible using Django.

Comment: Why don't you import the function you want from your console app and call it from Django instead?

Comment: i also tried that , its not working. not sure why.